# How to predict the length and offset of the sequence in and array?

Tags: algorithms, arrays, hash-tables

I have an input string similar to `ABCDEFGHIJK` from which a series of sequences has been generated into an array as following:

```
00: 'ABCD'
01: 'BCDE'
02: 'CDEF'
03: 'DEFG'
04: 'EFGH'
05: 'FGHI'
06: 'GHIJ'
07: 'HIJK'
08: 'ABC'
09: 'BCD'
10: 'CDE'
11: 'DEF'
12: 'EFG'
13: 'FGH'
14: 'GHI'
15: 'HIJ'
16: 'IJK'
17: 'AB'
18: 'BC'
19: 'CD'
20: 'DE'
21: 'EF'
22: 'FG'
23: 'GH'
24: 'HI'
25: 'IJ'
26: 'JK'
27: 'A'
28: 'B'
29: 'C'
30: 'D'
31: 'E'
32: 'F'
33: 'G'
34: 'H'
35: 'I'
36: 'J'
37: 'K'
```

The sequences in the array above has been generated by following these steps:

1. Set `length` to `4`
2. Set `offset` to `0`
3. Pick a `sequence` of `length` long characters from `"ABCDEFGHIJK" (Input string)`
4. Put the `sequence` at the bottom of `output array`
5. Increase `offset` by `1`
6. If `offset + length <= 11 (Input string's length)` then `goto 3`
7. Decrease `length` by `1`
8. If `length >= 1` then `goto 2`
9. Exit

By looking at the output array, sequences in the array have a `length` which starts at 4 and gradually goes down to 1, and also an `offset` which is where in the `input string` the `sequence` has begun.

What I'm trying to achieve is to "predict" both the `length` and the `offset` of a `sequence` at a given `index` in the `output array`, only having the `input string's length` and `index in the output array`.

I'm preferably looking for a formula, however an algorithm which doesn't involve simulating the output array will work as well.

Comment: @Evil I have edited the question. Please take a look now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n$ be the length of the string, and $k$ be the maximum length of the substring. Thus the first $n-k+1$ positions correspond to length $k$, the next $n-k+2$ to length $k-1$, and so on. Denote by $i_\ell$ the index at which substrings of length $k-\ell$ begin. We have
$$
i_\ell = \sum_{t=k-\ell+1}^k (n-t+1) = \frac{[(n-k+1)+(n-k+\ell)]\ell}{2} = \frac{\ell^2}{2} + \ell\left(n-k+\frac{1}{2}\right).
$$
Given $i_\ell$, we can solve for $\ell$:
$$
\ell = \sqrt{(n-k+1/2)^2+2i_\ell}-(n-k+1/2).
$$
Monotonicity shows that for *arbitrary* $i$, the floor of this expression still gives the correct value of $\ell$. This suggests the following algorithm:

1. Let $i$ be the input index.
2. Calculate $\ell = \lfloor \sqrt{(n-k+1/2)^2+2i}-(n-k+1/2) \rfloor$.
3. Calculate $i_\ell = \ell^2/2 + \ell(n-k+1/2)$.
4. Output length=$k-\ell$ and offset=$i-i_\ell$.

For example, let's take $i = 10$ in your case (where $n = 11$ and $k = 4$). Then $\ell = \lfloor \sqrt{7.5^2+20}-7.5 \rfloor = \lfloor 1.23\ldots \rfloor = 1$ and $i_\ell = 1^2/2 + 1\cdot 7.5 = 8$. Hence the length is $4-1=3$ and the offset is $10-8=2$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try the algorithm as soon as I'm home and let you know if I have any problems. :)

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: Great answer! I just saw it, after I posted mine. That is, what I have to practice!

Comment: @Yuval Filmus one difficulty I have while trying to implement the formula you provided is I can't figure out how to apply the minimum length. The minimum length might be bigger than 1 and I thing it should be included in the formula too, but I don't know how and where.

Comment: In fact, it shouldn't. Imagine you cut your list short at line 26. Would it affect in any way the calculations for line 10?

Comment: Oh! That's just wonderful @Yuval Filmus ! I wish I could do math like that. :) I'm currently busy implementing it in my code. Will get back to you as soon as I'm done. Only one question ⌊1.23...⌋ is the floor and not round, right? :)

Comment: Right, this is the floor.

Comment: Works wonderfully great. Thanks you very much @Yuval Filmus
I wish I could do math like you. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Variables

In this answer I will use the following names for the variables:

- The `n` variable refers to the initial value of `length` (in the case above this is 4)
- The `isl` (input string length) variable refers to the length of the input string (11 in the case above)
- The `index` variable refers to the index of the output array.

## Approach

To solve the problem and find a solution, we should first look at the details we got.

### Input

The formula or algorithm we are looking for receives the following inputs:

- The `index` of the `output_array`
- The `isl` (length of the input string)

But this is not the only input. It also knows the **initial value** of `length` (in your example above it's 4). As mentioned above, we will call this value `n`.

### Facts

From the algorithm you described in your question, we can derive the following facts:

#### Partitions of the output array

The `output_array` will have `n` partitions corresponding to the `n` different lengths (in your example above the lengths from 4 to 1).
Each partition `i` has a length of $$\text{isl}-(n-i)+1$$ where `i` (the partition number) starts at 0.
We notice, that the first partition is the smallest one and the last partition (where the `sequences` have a length of 1) is the largest one with a length of `isl`. From the formula we also see, that the length of the partitions increases from the first partition to last partition by 1.

*Note: We count partitions starting at 0.*

### Deducting the Formula

We need two formulas. One for the `length` of the `sequence` at `index` and one for the `offset` of that same `sequence` in the input string.

#### The formula for `length`

The formula for the `length` must look something like this: $$\text{length} = \overbrace{\text{n}}^{\text{minuend}} - \overbrace{\text{something depending on index}}^{\text{subtrahend}}$$

For the first partition (partition 0) the `subtrahend` shall be 0. For the second (partition 1) it shall be 1 and so on.

**Indicator function**

As we can see, we need a function, which can tell us, in which partition the `index` is in. A thing with such a property is like an indicator function. It could look like:

$$\text{partition_number}(\text{index}) = \begin{cases}0,&\text{if index in partition 0}\\1,&\text{if index in partition 1}\\\ldots\end{cases}$$

An easy way to find such a function is to have an indicator function, which can tell us, if `index` is in a partition `a`, where `a` is at least `i`. Something like:

$$f(\text{index},i) = \begin{cases}1,&\text{if index in partition a > i}\\0,&\text{else}\end{cases}$$

Because then we would just have to sum the result of `f` for all partitions and would directly have our subtrahend.

To define such a function `f`, we need to know at least the left boundary of partition `i`. We can obtain the left bound of partition `i` by:

$$\text{left_bound}(i) = i*\overbrace{(\text{isl}-n+1)}^{\text{Size of first partition}}+\overbrace{\frac{1}{2}*(i-1)*i}^{\text{Correction number for partition growth}}$$

So our *indicator function* looks like:

$$f(\text{index},i) = \begin{cases}1,&\text{if } \text{left_bound}(i)<=\text{index}\\0,&\text{else}\end{cases}$$

With this function we can now define our `partition_number` function as following:

$$\text{partition_number}(\text{index})=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{f(\text{index},i)}-1$$

With the `partition_number` for our subtrahend we can now define our formula for the `length_at_index`:

$$\text{length_at_index}=n-\text{partition_number}(\text{index})=n-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{f(\text{index},i)}+1$$

#### The formula for `offset`

We can directly make use of the `partition_number` and `left_bound` function we defined above:

$$\text{offset_at_index} = \text{index}-\text{left_bound}(\text{partition_number}(\text{index}))$$

## A Solution in Javascript

And here the solution of above written in Javascript:

```js
function getLeftBoundOfPartitionI(i, isl, n) {
    return i * (isl - n + 1) + .5 * (i - 1) * i
}

function isIndexInPartitionI(index, i, isl, n) {
  return index >= getLeftBoundOfPartitionI(i, isl, n) ? 1 : 0
}

function getPartitionNumber(index, isl, n) {
    partition = 0
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    partition += isIndexInPartitionI(index, i, isl, n)
  }
  return partition - 1
}

function lengthAtIndex(index, isl, n) {
    return n - getPartitionNumber(index, isl, n)
}

function offsetAtIndex(index, isl, n) {
  partitionNumber = getPartitionNumber(index, isl, n)
    return index - getLeftBoundOfPartitionI(partitionNumber, isl, n)
}

document.body.innerHTML = offsetAtIndex(16, 11, 4)  // yields 8
```

Comment: Thank you for the great effort @R. Qelibari I really appreciate it. However as you mentioned yourself, the solution Yuval Filmus explained is just wonderful. :)